# Maven Project Library Not Found

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, osgi

I have maven project where i am adding the dependencies which are not resolvable as below.

[image]

My servlet is as follows:

[image]

LocaleUtil is getting resolve but its sub packages are throwing error when including.

I have tried invalidate cache and restart. But this didn't work for me.

Thanks,

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages you are trying to import are internal, non-exported packages of the bundle `com.adobe.granite.i18n`. In fact, that bundle only exports the following packages:

```
Export-Package
  com.adobe.granite.i18n                 {version=1.0, imported-as=[1.0.0,1.1)}
  com.day.cq.i18n                        {version=5.4.0}
```

You should not attempt to use private packages of a library. Limit yourself to using only the exported API.